# Ionic Framework update to stable version

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

Trying to update previous Ionic Framework beta to v2. I have updated Cordova first, but the IonicFramework continues in beta instead of having run the update command.

This is the environment:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.3.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

And these are the issues when I do `sudo npm install -g ionic`:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: Use uuid module instead
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:15397) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
/usr/local/bin/ionic -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
/usr/local/lib
└── ionic@2.2.1 

npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of mime-types with mime-types@2.0.14
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of cross-spawn with cross-spawn@4.0.2
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of semver with semver@4.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of form-data with form-data@0.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of request with request@2.51.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try uninstalling ionic globally and then installing again:

```
npm unistall -g ionic
npm install -g ionic
```

Comment: I did but it still has 'Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11' and it throws the same warnings when installing, any idea?

Comment: try bumping to the stable version you want in package.json